# Adding observer to NSNotificationCenter second time causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: cocoa, ios, macos, nsnotificationcenter, observer-pattern

Hypothetical scenario:

In my `viewDidLoad` method I am adding view controller as an observer for custom notification (say, notification `MyFooNotification`). Later in the process when view is loaded the notification gets posted and controller processes it. When I leave the controller with it's view I DO NOT remove the observer (intentionally) in `viewDidUnload`. Next time when opening the view, the observer gets added again, but now when the observed notification gets posted - I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Can anyone explain why this is happenning.

P.S. I do know that I should remove it in `viewDidUnload` I'm just curious about the lower level details.

Comment: Sounds like something is getting released that shouldn't be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely because the original view controller has been deallocated because it was popped off a navigation stack (or similar), but `NSNotificationCenter` still has a reference to it. Thus when the notification is posted again, `NSNotificationCenter` attempts to notify the now deallocated view controller and gets `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` as a result.

If you *ever* have an object add itself to `NSNotificationCenter` as an observer you need to make sure you remove it during `dealloc`.